# Android Kotlin - Classifier 'Activity' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

```
        var acct = Activity

        when {
            activityName.contains("MainActivity", true) -> {
                acct = (context as MainActivity)

            }
            activityName.contains("UserMemes", true) -> {
                acct = (context as UserMemes)

            }
            activityName.contains("SearchShow", true) -> {
                acct = (context as SearchShow)

            }
        }

        acct.memeIdAndLastPos[meme.id] = scrollY
```

I get `Classifier 'Activity' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here` On `Activity`

When I do `Activity()` instead then the error disappears but I can't use `memeIdAndLastPos` any more.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val acct: Activity = when { 
  activityName.contains("MainActivity", true) ->  context as MainActivity
  activityName.contains("UserMemes", true) ->  context as UserMemes
  activityName.contains("SearchShow", true) -> context as SearchShow  
}

acct.memeIdAndLastPos[meme.id] = scrollY
```